# File Redirection into Program

Tags: c++, file-io, io-redirection

I'm having trouble with file redirection into my program. I have a Makefile called test and I want to redirect a text file into it as input. For example, I want to do:

test < file.txt

as input into my executable. However, I keep getting segmentation faults when I try to read the contents of file.txt. Here is my attempt:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE *a;
  int count;
  a = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  for(n = 0; ; n++)
  {
    count = fgetc(a); // <- here is where my program segfaults
    if(feof(a))
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Might anyone know why this occurs?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you for doing `eof` correctly!

Answer (score 2):

That's because the redirection is handled by the shell and not passed as an argument. When redirection is used, the file is used for `stdin`.

You should always check the result of function, in this case you try to call `fopen` with `NULL` as filename so it will return `NULL` leading to your segmentation fault.

Comment: `fgetc` is undefined with `NULL` as its argument (a "specialisation" of a non-stream argument, of course), then? That would appear to be the implication from the docs, though for some reason I'm surprised.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't have the C standard, but none of the references I have access to (including the POSIX standard which should be a copy of the actual C standard) mentions anything about using `NULL` as the file pointer, so I would say it's definitely undefined behavior. Presumably some implementations behaves as it's a proper pointer and accesses it without any checking.

Comment: Just trying to figure out why I'm surprised. I'd have expected a "safe" result possibly because of the tendency of POSIX functions to bail on error, including `fgetc` which is defined to return `EOF` on error (I'm not claiming that this should include the bad-input case; it's just interesting)

Comment: 7.19.7.1 doesn't mention any semantics for this case. Still surprised, though! Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The shell does not pass "<" and "file.txt" as arguments to the program, so your `argv[1]` is returning random garbage.

Instead of reading from `a`, you should read from `stdin`, which is automatically available and opened.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int count;
  for(n = 0; ; n++)
  {
    count = fgetc(stdin); 
    if(feof(stdin))
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```